# I was trying to add login feature through prompt inside react. But I was asked twice the same details by browser. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I was trying to implement login feature in the webpage such that when user give valid credentials then only render the content.
But Browser ask the same credentials twice. But why I have expected that it should ask only once?

Help me to fix this bug?

Comment: Please use text instead of images, or even better: a reproducible example. And what is `prompt`?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie i think it's javascript default function `window.prompt`

Comment: please learn more about javascript or logic you don't understand. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: @TachibanaShin Ah right, well, that function can't be used directly in a React component as it has side effects, so it should be inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie that's right. but I believe this is pretty sketchy code it needs extra storage like `cookie` or `Storage`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your variables in a state and implement a simple login page like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setUserId(prompt("Enter your user id:"));
    setPassword(prompt("Enter your password:"));
  };

  if (userId !== "abcd" || password !== "1234") {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleLogin}>
          Login
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Login successful</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-bhabha-vhbys3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to sandbox.

Using a `useEffect` will trigger the prompt twice during development unless you [disable strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-greider-etm02h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to sandbox with `useEffect`.